# Data Persistency, patterns and approaches

Tags: c#

Data persistency has recently become a really grip for me, especially how long to maintain database connectivity and how many connections are feasible for a given request.
I've been using .NET; however, this is a generic question related to any lanaguage.
From a .NET perspective, I'm connecting to database using EF4 and for a given website page I might create 6 connection per-request to render a page. The page might consist of news, stock prices, etc, and needs to be constantly updated.

I've recently been looking at unit-of-work (i.e. per request) approach. So basically when a request starts, if required a database connection is opened and destroyed upon end of the request. I'm not convinced it's the best approach yet. I'm looking for opinions and experience on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My general philosophy has always been that data access layers should be designed to be disconnected and stateless. In other words you have a database layer responsible for fetching different kinds of data and returning it and immediately disconnect the connection (throw it back on the pool)

If you have things like paging it should be implemented on the database level with the sp taking nr entries per page and page to fetch so you don't have to keep anything persistent in memory between requests.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the databases out there have a hard limit on number of connections - meaning, if you are to assign x number of connections per request, you will be hitting a ceiling very soon. You should look at connection pooling / caching db objects locally or in cache servers etc. Also db connection Init / destroy is a costly operation. Stick to pooling and let a proxy manage this for you in background.

This might not be a popular opinion, but I am not a big fan of connecting to the databases from the web servers directly either. One way to solve this is by adding additional service layers in between where in you can ensure the db is abstracted out. This way, you don't have to worry about scaling independently / changing db's  / partitioning / adding cache layers later.

Comment: I agree with the abstraction layer.  It could be a service layer that managed caching etc, or if warranted, a CQRS style architecture.  With a CQRS style you would likely use precomputed "views" of the data you need to serve a request and it wouldn't necessarily need to match the write model.

Answer (score 2):

I use a pool of connections. Every time I am done with one, I throw it on a stack. If I need one, I start popping off the stack until I encounter an active connection (connection that didn't timeout while it was in the queue). I use this approach because I have many requests/second and my connections get recycled very fast. They rarely have enough time to timeout inside the stack. Of course you will need to synchronize the Stack.
I use Redis as a database, but I assume it works for any type of connection which has an underlying socket.

Comment: Still you'll be doing a lot of IO actions to the database, which something I've been trying to avoid, unnecessary network traffic. You have pool of 10, then a unit of work might unnecessary try to open ten connections, yes only for second.  Problem you might be multiple this across thousands or users. The numbers will eventual add-up to the users waiting for open connection or IO traffic issues.